# Neo4J: find a sub-graph of arbitrary depth with nodes connected by a given set of relations?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, subgraph

How to build a Neo4J query that:

1) Will return all nodes in a sub-graph of arbitrary depth with nodes connected by a given set of relations?

For example in Cypher-like syntax:

```
MATCH (*)-[r1:FRIEND_OF AND r2:COLLEAGUE_WITH]->(*) RETURN *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return just the nodes, as you stated in your question:

```
MATCH (n)-[:FRIEND_OF|COLLEAGUE_WITH*]->(m)
RETURN n, m;
```

If you also want the relationships:

```
MATCH (n)-[r:FRIEND_OF|COLLEAGUE_WITH*]->(m)
RETURN n, r, m;
```

Comment: Thanks! What if there are several sub-graphs of this kind in a database which are disconnected from each other? In other words: there are several trees in a forest, where each tree has a root different from other tree roots. Nodes in all these distinct subtrees are connected with one and the same relation. What query will return all these trees?

Comment: The same query will match all the subgraphs. Try it out.