# Cypher: Matching nodes at arbitrary depth via a strictly alternating set of relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm quite new to Cypher but struggling to find how to do this. I want to generalise the following so that it will match at an arbitrary depth.

```
MATCH (:start)-[:a]-()-[:b]-(:end) //Depth1
MATCH (:start)-[:a]-()-[:b]-()-[:a]-()-[:b]-(:end) //Depth2
MATCH (:start)-[:a]-()-[:b]-()-[:a]-()-[:b]-()-[:a]-()-[:b]-(:end) //Depth3
MATCH (:start)-[:a]-()-[:b]-()-[:a]-()-[:b]-()-[:a]-()-[:b]-()-[:a]-()-[:b]-(:end) //Depth4
```

In other words, the path needs to pass through any number of *a-node-b* in strict alternation; *a-node-a* etc. will not work. So I can't do this, as per [Neo4J: find a sub-graph of arbitrary depth with nodes connected by a given set of relations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160713/neo4j-find-a-sub-graph-of-arbitrary-depth-with-nodes-connected-by-a-given-set-o)

```
MATCH (:start)-[:a|b*]-(:end)
```

because that would match things like this:

```
MATCH (:start)-[:a]-()-[:a]-(:end)
MATCH (:start)-[:b]-()-[:b]-(:end)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I'm using Cypher with Neo4j 2.x if it matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strict answer is no, this is not possible in Cypher. The stretched answer is: it's possible to determine whether such a path exists, and to return the nodes on either end of the path, but it's slow and you won't get to keep some of the information along the path.

```
MATCH (first) - [:a] -> () - [:b] -> (third)
MERGE (first) - [temp:c] -> (third)
WITH COLLECT(temp) AS temps
MATCH p = (:start) - [:c*] -> (:end)
WITH temps, COLLECT(p) AS ps
FOREACH(temp IN temps)|DELETE temp)
UNWIND ps AS p
RETURN DISTINCT p
```

This does require you to have a `:c` or other relationship type that you can use as a temp here.