# Cypher: Quantifying over zero or more node-then-relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to return all nodes **a** and **b**, where **b** is not downstream of **a** via any path that begins with relation **rel**. I keep finding myself having to write one condition for the case where **a** is linked directly to **b** via **rel**, and one for the indirect case, leading to something like this:

```
//Semi-pseudo-code.
match           (a)-[*]->(b)
optional match  dir=(a)-[:rel]->(b)
optional match  indir=(a)-[:rel]-()-[*]->(b)
where           length(dir)=0
and             length(indir)=0
return          a,b
```

Is there any easier way? Really I want something like this, where the bare quantifier means "zero or more nodes-then-relations":

```
match           (a)-[*]->(b)
match not       (a)-[:rel]-*->(b)
return          a,b
```

Note: I suspect this may at root be the same as my last question: [Cypher: Matching nodes at arbitrary depth via a strictly alternating set of relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330729/cypher-matching-nodes-at-arbitrary-depth-via-a-strictly-alternating-set-of-rela)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `WHERE NOT` to formulate negative conditions, in a similar fashion to your second semi-pseudocode:

```
MATCH     (a)-[*]->(b)
WHERE NOT ((a)-[:rel]->()-[*1..]->(b))
RETURN    a, b
```

Of course, this will be anything but efficient, so you should at least try to restrict the labels of `a` and `b` and the relationships between them, e.g. `(a:Label1)-[:rel1|rel2*]->(b:Label2)`

An example:

```
CREATE
  (n1:N {name: "n1"}),
  (n2:N {name: "n2"}),
  (n3:N {name: "n3"}),
  (n4:N {name: "n4"}),
  (n5:N {name: "n5"}),
  (n1)-[:x]->(n2),
  (n3)-[:rel]->(n4),
  (n4)-[:x]->(n5)
```

[image]

The query results in:

```
╒══════════╤══════════╕
│a         │b         │
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│{name: n1}│{name: n2}│
├──────────┼──────────┤
│{name: n4}│{name: n5}│
└──────────┴──────────┘
```

As you can see, it does not include `n3` and `n5`, as it starts with a `:rel` relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But won't your code still match the direct case?:
    (a)-[:rel]->(b)
I need to exclude that. (Or have I misunderstood?)

Comment: Good point - [variable length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#_variable_length_relationships) default to a `minHops` value of 1. I fixed the query and will add an example in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
MATCH (a)-[rs*]->(b)
WHERE TYPE(rs[0]) <> 'rel'
RETURN a, b;
```

However, the query below should be much more performant, as it filters out all unwanted path beginnings *before* it does the very expensive variable-length path search. The `*0..` syntax makes the variable-length search use a lower bound of 0 for the length (so `x` will also be returnable as `b`).

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(x)
WHERE TYPE(r) <> 'rel'
MATCH (x)-[*0..]->(b)
RETURN a, b;
```